# Is something wrong with the Schedule Reminder auto renewals for membership? I cannot find "Membership End Date" in list.

Tags: scheduled-reminders

Description of issue:
[As per these instructions](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/scheduled-reminders/), am trying to setup a scheduled email reminder to all of our members 5 days before their membership expires. Our membership has a rolling intake date, so each of these emails is going to go out on a different day. I am relying on a tool to send these out according to a certain set of rules.

I am using the Schedule Reminder tool. After picking membership types (group of people to whom I want to send these email reminders; in the example below it is to the group of members in the "Individual" category), I want to set a specific amount of time prior to their "Membership End Date" for the emails to go out. Instead, when I go to pick "Membership End Date" from the dropdown menu, all I see in the drop down list is one entry called "Activity Date Time" (which to me seems like the generic one).

The documentation leads me to believe that this should be real simple and that dropdown should be pre-populated with that field - and I don't see anywhere to add something custom. 
[image]

fig.1 Documentation suggests Membership End Date should be readily available and easy to find.

[image]

fig. 2 showing no options other than a generic "Activity Date Time" in dropdown menu

I am confident that there should be other options here/ 
Here is an example from StackOverflow i came across during some research. 
[image]
fig.3 img shared by stackoverflow user in an unrelated discussion on setting up scheduled reminders that shows a type of

I am not sure what's up.. whether its just me.

---

Other perhaps related issues?
On the off chance that these are related (ie, the plugin is not picking up on some folder or DB full of important arrays or images), I thought I would document a couple other weird things I noticed along the way:

I noticed that the calendar function (fig.2; which I don't need in this case) is not working.

[image]
fig.4

In the dashboard,  I noticed that the menu items seem to have little images that are not populating. fig.3
[image]

fig.5 dashboard menu showing missing images

Comment: Hi Anders - welcome to civicrm stackexchange. It would help people shed some light on your problem if you could include what version of civicrm you are running (This should be visible at the bottom of the screen). Also I think your fig 2 might be missing?

Comment: Thanks for the response Luke! Good point and will do in future. We're running CiviCRM 5.40 .. and it was around the time we updated to a newer version that this issue popped up. I have an update from a colleague who helped me out. 

"Turns out that  
running this command via SSH seems to have fixed the broken calendar and weird path things: 
wp civicrm api System.rebuildmultilingualschema"

We're gonna put off updating the plug-in for a while not that we've got it working again.

Answer (score 1):

Those other 'issues' suggest you need to review your Directories and/or Resource URLs under Admin > System Settings.

IN terms of does Membership End Date get offered as an option after choosing Entity = Membership - yes - and here is screenshot from https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/scheduleReminders?action=add&reset=1 to show what is happening on a fully functioning site.

Hope the above hints help

[image]